# How to add a user defined tag in an MP3 file?

Tags: perl

Can anyone explain to me how to add a user defined tag in an MP3 file using the [MP3::Tag](http://p3rl.org/MP3%3a%3aTag) module in Perl? I have done some sample programs.

```
# Created an object
$mp3 = MP3::Tag->new($filename);

# Getting the already defined tags for the file
@tags = $mp3->get_tags();
```

My question is: how to add a user defined tag, for example the tag `Name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly edited from the [module's synopsis](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MP3-Tag/lib/MP3/Tag.pm#SYNOPSIS)

```
$mp3->update_tags({name => 'blah blah'});    # Edit in-memory, and commit to file
```

Comment: define, "data". the "blah blah" in my answer is the data that will be associated with the tag "name" in the mp3 referenced by `$mp3`...